# Building a binary tree from a string

Tags: c++, recursion, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to build a tree from a string. The string is of the form: ((. (.A.E))(.I.O)), where the 5 leaf nodes of the tree are represented with a period.

I'm unable to determine how to solve this problem; I've tried tweaking the solution to a similar problem offered on this website: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/construct-binary-tree-string-bracket-representation/.

Would really appreciate any help you could provide, as I prepare for coding interviews.

Thanks!

Comment: The picture does not represent a BST, it is simply a tree. `'Z'` is not less than `'A'`, unless you are ordering your tree in reverse, but then `'n'` and `'A'` would not be in reverse order.

Comment: Sorry--to clarify, it's just a tree; the idea of the problem is more so just to translate a string sequence into a tree

Comment: OK, that makes more sense, because a *"Binary Search Tree"* (or BST) is a very specific kind of tree with very specific ordering requirements. What part are you stuck at? The only subtlety they don't discuss is pushing and popping from the stack they use to track the opening and closing `'('` and `')'`. The rest should be fairly straight forward. Also, for help here, you need to post [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, we are just guessing where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

As I see this, there are just some rules to be followed. Based on the character being processed you have the following options:

1. If it's a "(", it means you must build your tree deeper, either to the left or to the right, based on the actions you took prior to this one
2. If it's a ".", you should read the next element in the string to determine the node value and after that you should go back one step in the recursion as the "." represents a leaf
3. If it's a ")", that means you finished building the subtree of a node and so you must go back one step in the recursion again

Some advices about how to implement this:

1. Write a recursive function that takes a string as input
2. The function should also return a string representing the string that remains to be further processed
3. If at any step your string is empty it means that the string given to be processed is not valid
4. You should check for the ")" every time you finish building the left or right subtree of a node

Hope this helps and good luck at your interviews!

Comment: "Write a recursive function that takes a string as input"?? This part is unclear. (and also of dubious advice where the exit condition and goal of the recursive call isn't stated)

Comment: Thanks! I've been trying to implement this, but was wondering if you could clarify what you mean by building the tree deeper "based on the actions you took prior to this one"--how would I determine this? And what do you mean by "go back one step in the recursion" in the case of leaf and )? If you wouldn't mind pseudo-coding this, that would be very helpful! I've been staring at this for hours and haven't been able to come up with a working solution--I tried the one in the link in my question, but haven't been able to adapt it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I came up with is an iterative solution based on a stack. It has a few rules to follow:

1. push anything that comes to the stack
2. If you encounter `)` of the stack, start removing elements untill you encounter a `(`, and then pop that out too.
3. When you pop the elements in step 2, store them in a vector, except `)` and `(`.
4. Create a tree Node and mark the parent's children as all the elements in the vector.
5. push the parent Node back onto the stack.

Let's see with your example:
`S = "((a($Z))(An))"`, changed `' ' -> 'a'` for clarity.

**Note**: Stack growing towards the right.

```
Stack["((a($Z"]
encounter ')'
Stack["((a"], vector<"Z$">
reverse vector -> vector<"$Z">
Parent Node -> N(id='1'), children -> <N(id='$'), N(id='Z')>
push N(1) to stack

Stack["((a1]
encounter ')'
Stack["("], vector<"1a">
reverse vector -> vector<"a1">
Parent Node -> N(id='2'), children -> <N(id='a'), N(id=1)>
push N(2) to stack

Stack["(2(An"]
encounter ')'
...
```

you can continue this to get to the top. When you are done, i.e. the string is exhausted, you will get exactly one element left in the stack which would be your parent element or the root of the tree.

Code:

```
Node* solve(string s) {
    stack<Node *> st;
    int idx = 0, rt = 1;
    while (idx < s.size()) {
        Node *n = get_node(s[idx]);
        st.push(n);
        ++idx;

        if (st.top()->v == ')') {
            st.pop();
            vector<Node *> child;
            while (st.size() && st.top()->v != '(') {
                child.push_back(st.top()); st.pop();
            }
            if (st.top()->v == '(') st.pop();

            Node *par = get_node('0' + rt++);
            reverse(child.begin(), child.end());
            for (Node *t : child) {
                t->parent = par;
                par->child.push_back(t);
            }
            st.push(par);
        }
    }
    return st.top();
}
```

[Full Working code](https://ideone.com/DvGkPd)

This code is a general implementation, so any node can have as many children, so n-arry tree construction.
eg:

```
input: ((a($Zk))(An))
output:
Parent: 4: 2 3
Parent: 2: a 1
Parent: 3: A n
Parent: 1: $ Z k
```

Comment: Thanks so much @pikaynu, this is very helpful. I'm trying to find a way to do this recursively, so if you have any tips on that, I'd appreciate it!